# Finding the smallest integer for filling a m×n board with consecutive integers in each row and column

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, chessboard

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Find the smallest positive integer $s$ for which there exists an $m \times n$ rectangular array of positive integers such that:

1. Each row contains $n$ distinct consecutive integers in some order,
2. Each columm contains $m$ distinct consecutive integers in some order,
3. Each entry is less than or equal to $s$

For example,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a legal (and in fact minimal in terms of $s$) solution when $m = 2, n=4$.

**I can show that if $m=n$ then the answer is $m$. But can someone help me with the other cases?**

Comment: can you explain why when $m$ divides $n$, the answer is $\max(m, n)$, for example when $m = 2$ and $n = 4$?

Comment: @LearningMathematics In that case, the answer is indeed 4. Let the entries be $\{\{1,2\},\{2,1\},\{3,4\},\{4,3\}\}$.

Comment: @Adina Goldberg yeah, I realised it later...okay, so the explanation is. We can fill a m×m grid with Integers starting from 1 to m or any other set of m consecutive integers. If m|n, we fill each m×m array with m consecutive integers with the first array starting with 1 and then, each array after that starting with a number 1 more than the maximum number of the previous array.

Comment: A guess that fits all of the formulae so far is $m + n - \gcd(m,n)$

Comment: The phrase "proceeded till the fact" doesn't make much sense. Could you please rephrase your description of what you've found and where you're stuck?

Comment: @Barry Cipra I couldn't figure out the answer when m does not divide n or vice versa whichever you consider

Answer (score 1):

Letting $a_{i,j}$ denote the number in the $i$th row, $j$th column, we see by looking at the first row that
$$
a_{1,n} - a_{1,1} = n-1.
$$

Similarly, looking at the last column, we see that
$$
a_{m, n} - a_{1,n} = m-1.
$$
Adding these together, we get that
$$
a_{m,n} - a_{1,1} = n + m - 2.
$$
So if $a_{1,1} = 1$, then $a_{m,n} = 1 + (n-1) + (m-1) = n + m - 1$.

So to fill up the whole array, you need the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n+m-1$.

Comment: Oh, wait. I see. The first row contains the numbers $1, \ldots, n$, which are "consecutive", but they don't have to be written in "consecutive order" -- it could be $2, 3, 1, 4$, for instance. Well...that's a frustratingly hard-to-read question, and I leave my (wrong) answer here so that this comment can explain to others why not to approach it this way.

Comment: @ John Hughes yeah ik, can you think of any other solution?

Comment: Nope...once I realized I'd wasted time writing out this answer, I lost interest. If you want people to work on your problems, it's a good idea to spend some time crafting the question so that it's as clear as it can be -- examples often help, for instance. If you want to have fun by writing questions with obscure little tricks, puzzling stack exchange actually has some good fun with those.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a point of confusion over the word 'consecutive'.  I believe it is a universal understanding that it means each successive integer is one more than the preceding one, i.e that the values are $N, N+1, N+2, ..., N+K$ for some $N, K.$  In that case, assuming the (say) upper-left corner of the matrix is $1$, then the value of $s$ is $(m + n - 1)$.  Example for $m=3$, $n=4$:

```
 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5
 3 4 5 6
```

If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: What you have shown is absolutely correct, infact my intuition is if m does not divide n or vice versa then then answer is $m+n-1$, I don't know if it's right..

Comment: but apart from the combination you have shown there can be other combinations as well, u need to show that $m+n-1$ will be the minimum for all $m,n$ not for one such example

Answer (score 0):

I give a partial answer (an upper bound on $s$ which I also believe is the lower bound).

**Claim:** $s \leq m + n - \gcd(m,n)$

**Proof:** Let $g:= \gcd(m,n)$. Divide the matrix into square blocks of size $g$. Write $m = r g, n = c g$, so $r$ is the number of block rows and $c$ is the number of block columns. Denote each block as $B_{i,j}$, so our original rectangular array can be written as such.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1} &\dots  &B_{1,c}\\
\vdots & &\vdots\\
B_{r,1} &\dots & B_{r,c}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that each block is square, and so given any $k$ consecutive numbers, a block can be legally filled by filling the first row with the given numbers, and then applying consecutive cyclic shifts to the numbers to fill each subsequent row.

A solution can always be obtained by filling the blocks as follows. Start in the upper left corner and then fill each diagonal as follows. Fill the upper left block with $\{1,\dots,g\}$, then fill blocks $B_{1,2}$ and $B_{2,1}$ with the numbers $\{g+1, \dots, 2g\}$, etc. In general, fill block $B_{i,j}$ with the numbers $\{ (i+j-2)g + 1, \dots, (i+j-2)g + g\}$. The maximum number reached will be in block $B_{r,c}$, and it will be $(r+c-2)g + g = m + n - g$.